# react-beautiful-dnd draggable flickering (but only some of the draggables children)

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, flicker, react-beautiful-dnd

I am having trouble getting react-beautiful-dnd to work because children of the draggable are flickering after reordering:

[image: ezgif-4-bd9d8ec129]

**No external requests happen in the background, the app stores the change only in the local state (see first code block `reorderElements()`).**

**What really confuses me is how only the 2 checkboxes flicker, but not the text or the icon.**

The list rerenders only once after reorder (asynchronously when the state is updated)

I suspect the asynchronous nature of useState to be the issue. But the fact that only those 2 checkboxes flicker contradicts the suspicion in my opinion.

The `draggableId` is updated after each reorder to the index of each element.

Here is the code:

My reorder function that is called `onDragEnd`:

```
function reorderElements({ source, destination }: any) {
    if (!destination) {
      return;
    }
    setAppState((oldAppState: AppState | null) => {
      if (oldAppState) {
        const { content } = oldAppState;
        const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(content));
        const [elementToMove] = copy.splice(source.index, 1);
        copy.splice(destination.index, 0, elementToMove);
        const elementsWithNewIndex = copy.map(
          (e: BannerElement, i: number) => ({
            ...e,
            id: "" + i,
          })
        );
        return { ...oldAppState, content: elementsWithNewIndex };
      }
      return null;
    });
  }
```

The list component

```
<DragDropContextContainer onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
        <DroppableContainer direction="horizontal" droppableId="root">
          {(provided: DroppableProvided) => (
            <div
              style={{ display: "flex" }}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              className="draggable-container-custom"
            >
              <>
                {content.map((element, index) => (
                  <Element
                    key={index}
                    index={index}
                    element={element}
                    updateElement={updateElement}
                    deleteElement={deleteElement}
                    provided={provided}
                    nElements={nElements}
                  />
                ))}
                {provided.placeholder}
              </>
            </div> 
          )}
        </DroppableContainer>
      </DragDropContextContainer>
```

DragDropContextContainer

```
export function DragDropContextContainer({ children, ...props }: Props) {
  return <DragDropContext {...props}>{children}</DragDropContext>;
}
```

DroppableContainer

```
export function DroppableContainer({ children, ...props }: Props) {
  return <Droppable {...props}>{children}</Droppable>;
}
```

Each Element

```
<DraggableContainer draggableId={id} index={index} key={index}>
      {(provided: DraggableProvided, snapshot: DraggableStateSnapshot) => {
        const draggableStyle = snapshot.isDragging
          ? { ...customDraggableStyle, ...provided.draggableProps.style }
          : provided.draggableProps.style;
        return (
          <div
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            {...provided.draggableProps}
            style={draggableStyle}
            className="draggable-custom"
          >
            <div
              {...provided.dragHandleProps}
              className="element-drag-icon-container"
            >
              <div className="element-drag-icon">
                <PolarisIcon source={DragHandleMinor} color={"base"} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="element-container">
              <div className="element-icon-container">
                <Checkbox
                  label="Text has Icon Prefix"
                  checked={hasIcon}
                  onChange={(newValue) => {
                    updateElement({ id, hasIcon: newValue });
                  }}
                />
                <Icon
                  disabled={!hasIcon}
                  key={JSON.stringify(icon)}
                  id={id}
                  elementIcon={icon}
                  updateElement={updateElement}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="element-text-container">
                <TextField
                  label="Set your Text:"
                  multiline={3}
                  value={text}
                  onChange={(text: ElementText) => {
                    updateElement({ id, text });
                  }}
                  autoComplete="off"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="element-bottom-row">
                <Checkbox
                  label="Show on mobile"
                  checked={showMobile}
                  onChange={() => {
                    updateElement({ id, showMobile: true });
                  }}
                />
                  <Button
                    plain
                    destructive
                    onClick={() => {
                      deleteElement(id);
                    }}
                  >
                    delete
                  </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </DraggableContainer>
  );
```

DraggableContainer

```
export function DraggableContainer({ children, ...props }: Props) {
  return <Draggable {...props}>{children}</Draggable>;
}
```

Those container-Components exist to get rid of some ESLint errors.

- Console logs nothing regarding this package.
- im using `"react": "^17.0.2"` and `"react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0"`
- tested in Chrome `Version 108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) (arm64)`

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case the problem was caused by the Polaris library and I have not found a solution to it.

I avoided the issue by switching to vanilla checkboxes (`<input/>`) which look almost identical.